# What's the reason clear_page_c_e is eating most CPU time here?

Tags: linux, rust, profiling

Consider this file:

```
extern crate csv;
use std::error::Error;
use std::process;
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(false)
        .delimiter(b'\t')
        .from_reader(io::stdin());
    let mut stdout_buf = io::BufWriter::new(io::stdout());
    for result in rdr.records() {
        let record = result.unwrap();
        for (i, item) in record.iter().enumerate() {
            write!(stdout_buf, "{}", item);
        }
    }
}
```

In `Cargo.toml`, the only dependency is `csv = "1.0.0-beta.3"`. If I feed this program with a large tab-separated file, I initially get 100MiB/s parsing speed, but after a few seconds it drops to less than half a megabyte per second. Here's what took most time according to `perf`:

```
Samples: 91K of event 'cycles:pp', Event count (approx.): 70889999629                                                                                                       
Overhead  Command     Shared Object       Symbol                                                                                                                            
  46.63%  csv_mapper  libc-2.17.so        [.] __memcpy_ssse3_back                                                                                                           
  34.68%  csv_mapper  [kernel.kallsyms]   [k] clear_page_c_e                                                                                                                
   5.66%  csv_mapper  csv_mapper          [.] csv_core::reader::Reader::read_record::hc2c3417e5570c6ac                                                                      
   3.38%  csv_mapper  csv_mapper          [.] csv::byte_record::validate::hf69692f1aec60002                                                                                 
   0.82%  csv_mapper  csv_mapper          [.] csv_mapper::main::h84d39cb33f062b66                                                                                           
   0.79%  csv_mapper  csv_mapper          [.] core::fmt::write::h3f842b6303ea2a70                                                                                           
   0.78%  csv_mapper  csv_mapper          [.] _$LT$std..io..Write..write_fmt..Adaptor$LT$$u27$a$C$$u20$T$GT$$u20$as$u20$core..fmt..Write$GT$::write_str::h0002300cbe68df34  
   0.69%  csv_mapper  csv_mapper          [.] core::str::from_utf8::h1297230116307e46                                                                                       
   0.42%  csv_mapper  csv_mapper          [.] mallocx
```

What could be happening here? Tested on `rustc 1.20.0-nightly (d84693b93 2017-07-09)`, x86_64, CentOS 7.3.

Comment: My first search result for `clear_page_c_e` is [clear_page_c_e eating lots of cpu](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/kernel/199904-clear_page_c_e-eating-lots-cpu.html) and the second is [Hidden Costs of Memory Allocation](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/hidden-costs-of-memory-allocation/). Perhaps if you clarify what you don't understand from those references, you will get a better answer. Once you have done that, you should figure out the call stack to `clear_page_c_e`; that will show you what's calling it (thus causing it).

Comment: [`Stdout` is already buffered](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdout.html), so you shouldn't need the extra buffer.

Comment: you might want to compile with debug information and `perf record -g` which should give you stack traces and source annotations in `perf report`. that might provide insight what's triggering it from userspace

Comment: How are you measuring parsing speed?